# Automatically share new photos with photo stream?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photo-stream

Is it possible to make every new photo taken automatically appear in a photo stream that is shared with other users?

Either by some how share the default photo stream or make another photo stream as default. Note that I don't want to jailbreak and I wont use any other application then those that are built in.

Answer (score 2):

No - I'd suggest dropbox as an alternative. It's still not flawless since you need to open the app to start pushing new pictures after taking them.

Here is some discussion surrounding the dropbox implementation:

- [Two Photo Streams, one iPhoto library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42984/two-photo-streams-one-iphoto-library)
- [Can photos taken with my iPhone (and Apple ID) stream to my husband's iPad (and Apple ID)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82451/can-photos-taken-with-my-iphone-and-apple-id-stream-to-my-husbands-ipad-and)

Alternatively, you could use a specialized app that includes automatic upload, for those are dime a dozen.

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative,

Since iOS 7 includes built in Flickr integration, you can set photos to automatically upload from your camera roll to your Flickr account (as long as you also download the free Flickr app).

The original question does state that no third party apps are wanted, however since that is not an option, I wanted to offer this alternative.